# Keycloak/Red Hat SSO 7.0 : Display accountTemporarilyDisabledMessage

Tags: single-sign-on, redhat, freemarker, keycloak

In Keycloak/Red Hat SSO 7.0, the base theme ships with a message bundle including accountTemporarilyDisabledMessage.

In the login theme, how do I detect that Keycloak has thrown the AuthenticationFlowError.USER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED exception so that I can display this message rather than continuing to inaccurately report "Invalid username/password" (the default behavior)?

Keycloak/Red Hat SSO user Freemarker Templates to render their UI pages. So essentially I just need the name of the hook to reference in the login.ftl but there are no examples of this I can find.

Like @kiml42 in the known duplicate below, I'm trying to avoid having to make rest service calls to a server that is already being exposed by the Freemarker system they have set up.

Known duplicate question: 
[Keycloak: Indicate user is temporarily locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467004/keycloak-indicate-user-is-temporarily-locked)

Related Issues:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4036
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/3972/files/d1343ed8489c7635ad820687667f6bc38d8dfa54